# android push notification using C2DM

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

i'm currently working on push notification in android using C2DM server . as i'm able to send the message to the server but i'm unable to get the response to my device, i dont understand where i'm stucked up plzz if anyone has worked on it then kindly help me out.

-pravin21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look out https://github.com/tomasmalmsten/c2dm-android-pilot (greatest c2dm sample ever, thanks to Tomas Malmsten :D ) 
you have to recieve your sessionId from google first. 
check your 1. session id 2. Google mail address(which is certificated or not)

Comment: Thankyou for your reply i hope it will help me in my code. but this link is already referred by me and i'm getting registration ID and authentication Id. how do i know whether the session Id is certificated or not? and i haven't came across session Id before this.

Comment: Did you checked that your test device is signed with market application?

Comment: i have a doubt in using it. how do 3rd party appl server communicates with C2DM? how actually it comes to know that the message is been send to C2DM?

Comment: the communication between 3rd party and device is occured through the market application. check the broadcast reciever and set the breakpoint when google send the message with intent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give permission for that

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. All the permissions for receiving , intent registration, unregistration have already given still its not working. if you know how the 3rd party server and the C2DM communicates then it would be helpful for me as my message is send successfully to server but i'm not confirmed rather not sure whether the 3rd party server is communicating with c2dm or not?